# Is God a noumenon? And why?

Tags: kant, noumenon

Is God a [noumenon](https://www.britannica.com/topic/noumenon) and why God is considered a noumenon? If I have personally experienced God then is it a noumenon or phenomenon from my point of view ?

Comment: _Every spiritual experience starts with a sensation in the body_ [Sri Anirban](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anirvan). The _experience_ of God is a phenomenon. The mature mystic knows that the reality-noumenon behind (any) experience is ever unknowable.  See [Meister Eckhart](https://www.goodnews.ie/wisdomlinemaytwo.shtml)

Comment: By definition, the noumenon can't be experienced. Asking if something is, or if it is part of the noumenon makes the question ill-formed: we don't, we can't know anything about the noumenon. He who answers yes/no is entering the fallacy. On the other hands, any question involving God should define it before: for example, if God is a person, conclusions raise naturally.

Comment: Which god? Are you implying a Christian or at least Abrahamic god? I'm asking because your name and the religion stacks you participate in appear to indicate a non-Christian background, but Kant surely had a Christian one. Maybe your question is not a "factual" one (a funny term when discussing transcendentals, I know!) but rather: "Did *Kant consider* the Christian god a noumenon?", or perhaps "Did *Kant as a Christian* consider the god he believed in a noumenon?".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I mean God as Kant had used.

Comment: @DheerajVerma Which is, from the standpoint of an adherent of a different religion (not necessarily you -- I'm speaking in general) an interesting question: That person would hold it as a truth that Kant's god does not exist, which renders important parts of Kant's philosophy utterly wrong and mistaken. What does that say about the rest of his philosophy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tagged this question with Kant, so I will answer from his texts first.

The most comprehensive writing about what God is is his second critique, the *Critique of Practical Reason* (CPrR). There following the first critique, God is a "mere" trancendental idea. Transcendental ideas are, in a sense, concepts our reason *needs to posit in spite of no correspondence in experience* in order to make sense of the world (ie. empirical reality).

The need to posit God, in the CPrR, arises since a) we are compelled to morality by the Moral Law, b) moral behaviour evidently does not necessarily lead to happiness, rather to the contrary oftentimes, and c) the highest good is the combination of a purely moral and at the same time happy world. Thus, he writes, reason posits an eternal soul and God in order to make the highest good even possible, if only in the afterlife. The role of God here is to ensure that morality and happiness of the soul are in proportionality; nothing more, nothing less. Basically because it is at least rational to assume that of God while we are not able to *know* anything about Him.

Now, why is God not a noumenon? This is a bit tricky. There are some shady parts (for example in the *Groundwork*) where he does count God into the noumenal realm, basically as the king of necessarily moral beings. Generally, for him, God is only to be experienced through the moral law, though, which means we have no phenomenal experience of him.

If one chooses to think otherwise, God becomes equally indubitable as the moral law. At least in the Kantian framework, this amounts only to *subjective* apodictic certainty, ie. faith, not also objective apodictic certainty, ie. knowledge, because every experience of God is purely *personal* and cannot be shared interpersonally in the same sense as sensual experience. Modern philosophers may say God lacks the same "this-ness" as the sensual objects of experience. Compared to the moral law, one starts to wonder how Kant was able to uphold this strict differentiation.

Comment: +1 for your Kant exegesis. It always clarifies for me what Kant possibly means  - here and elsewhere. - I would really like to know how you assess the stringency of Kant's argumentation, and also what you consider the driving force behind Kant's sophisticated ideas on the fields of religion and of ethics.

Comment: @JoWehler One has to keep in mind that Kant never even aspired to write strict proofs. He wants to write deductions in the juridical sense, ie. *establish principles beyond reasonable doubt*. Only from there, there are more or less rigorous inferences. The driving force behind his practical philosophy was his insight that classical metaphysics are dead because of his own philosophy, ie. he needed to establish a philosophy strictly based on experience and  and nevertheless "making place for faith", ie. somehow find a place for religion.

Comment: I agree that Kant wanted to make place for faith - so are his words. Nevertheless to base philosophy on experience and to find place for religion prompts the alternative: Either to reconcile experience with religion or to separate them as two completely disjoint domains. Sometimes Kant looks to me like attempting to square the circle by introducing rather heavyweight concepts.

Comment: @JoWehler I agree, but one has to keep in mind that people still were shunned and had to leave university if their philosophy seemed remotely blasphemic  back then.